# Where can I get this HTML editor

Tags: html, editor

Hey I see a HTML editor here [killerthoughts.com](http://killerthoughts.com). Where can I get it?? Or anything like it?

Thanks

Comment: I can't believe I didn't check the src:-/. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The page source says that it's [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Its a **[WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)**.

You can take a look at

**[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)**

**[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)**

**[YUI Rich text editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)**.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ckeditor

http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [**CKEditor**](http://ckeditor.com/).